# Should install Eclipse IDE for EE Developers OR plain IDE for Java Developers?

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee

I am new to Java EE. I want to start from servlet development using Eclipse. Do I need to install Eclipse EE version OR plain Eclipse version for Java to start Java E for web development?

**EDIT**

Actually bec java ee is so vast & I want to start with minimum i.e. web development.I also don't want to use huge eclipse Java EE version if plain Java version would do for web development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Eclipse has different flavors, so pick the one that works for you.  Java EE includes the servlet/JSP piece you need.  I'd go with that.

Comment: @so pick the one that works for you: that's what my question actually is. Actually bec java ee is so vast & I want to start with minimum i.e. web development.I also don't want to use huge eclipse Java EE version if plain Java version would  do for web development.

Comment: I think I said "Java EE" in that last sentence.  It means you might have to read some of the docs that accompany the different versions to figure out what you really need.

Comment: @user701854, if you got with plain Eclipse Java IDE, you will have to validate your XML yourself, and configure your project to conform like a web applications yourself (e.g. creating `WEB-INF` folder, `META-INF` folder, `WEB-INF/lib` folder, `src` folder, etc.). Eclipse JEE has all these validations and structures built-in for ease of use and development.

Comment: The Elite Gentleman:  thank you
but I have one concern, that I have not find any tutorial for web development OR servlet using eclipse EE version.

Comment: @The Elite Gentleman
do you have link of some good beginner web/servlet development tutorial??

Comment: My best recommendation would be to forget about Eclipse and use IntelliJ by JetBrains.  They make the best IDEs on the market, hands down.  (No, I don't work for them.  I'm a long-time, satisfied customer.)

Answer (score 3):

Install [Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/moreinfo/jee.php). This flavour of Eclipse is bundled with *everything* to start building Java EE applications. Download the Latest Release (Eclipse Helios) [here](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/).

Comment: with _everything to start_ you mean _everything wich slows down your start_ of Eclipse

Comment: But it does answer the question.

Comment: @mbx, NetBeans is worse, from **my** experience. Even though I run a decent machine here, I always have to run NetBeans with Task Manager so that when it freezes, I can kill it (since 2002 to this very day). Not had that experience with Eclipse at all.

Comment: @The Elite Gentleman I didn't wanted to point to NetBeans - wich I use for C++/Qt and embedded Java things. The Eclipse for Java (without EE) is just fine - if you don't really need EE Support, why making Eclipse slower?

Comment: @mbx, because it makes making JEE applications more dubious whereas, with Eclipse JEE, you can create what you want (e.g. `web.xml`, web application, `servlet`, etc.) with just a click.

Comment: @The Elite Gentleman maybe it's just me - I prefer to have the components I use, if one day I have to use EE features I pull those components then. It's a kind of _lazy evaluation_...

Comment: @mbx, maybe it's just you :-) I prefer having everything because you never know when you'll need it. Always be prepared! That's IT I live in. :-)

Comment: I don't use Eclipse or NetBeans; I'm an IntelliJ user.  It's the best IDE on the market, hands down.

Answer (score 0):

Its better to install Eclipse J2EE, because it pre configured WTP support, which you need to develop JSP/Servlet also has support for J2EE container like tomcat, jrun etc, and many more thing.....

Comment: Eclipse J2EE is outdated, rather the OP should get Eclipse IDE for **JEE** Developers.

Comment: J2EE is so 1998.  They dropped the "2" long ago - I think it's been about 5-6 years.